# React router 4 routing stopped working after changing from HashRouter to browserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a simple react application with my router below

index.tsx

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <HashRouter>
          <AppContainer />
        </HashRouter>
      </PersistGate>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app') as HTMLElement);
```

My AppContainer

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
        console.log("The state is here and now ", state);
        return {
            account: state.account,
        }
    }
     const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
            return {
                getUsers: () => dispatch(actions.fetchUser()),
            }
        };

        export default withRouter<any>(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(AppComponent));
```

and my AppComponent render method reyurns

```
   render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-app">    

                    <Route exact path='/' component={HomeContainer} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/home" component={HomeContainer} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={AboutContainer} />

            </div>
        )
    }
```

My app was working fine, then we decided we needed to use BrowserRouter instead. Simply changing my index.tsx to

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Router>
          <AppContainer />
        </Router>
      </PersistGate>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app') as HTMLElement);
```

Breaks my routing. Now it stays on the first route regardless. I have tried everything and somewhere , someone suggested changing my publicPath in webpack from empty to / . I did yet nothing change. Please what am i missing. I have tried everything yet to no aveil . Any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: by  any change does the url contains # in it. Also are you trying to navigate using web url or links within your app

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i am trying to navigate using web url. It doesn't work even without the hash

Comment: Also i try navigating using the Link component of react-router-dom, yet it doesn't change or navigate.